# AVAssetWriter error code 561211770

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying create a movie file with image/audio. The audio output format properties,

```
{ AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVEncoderBitRateKey : @120000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @1, AVSampleRateKey : @44100.0 };
```

Video output format properties,

```
{ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : @(600), AVVideoHeightKey : @(400) };
```

When I do finishWritingWithCompletionHandler on AVAssetWriter I get this error message on iPhone 7. Exactly same code works on iPhone 4s/5s.

> did not save due to error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
>   Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x14e1eb90 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=561211770 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
>   occurred (561211770)}

What's the meaning of this specific error code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I worked with it. This is settings which I used:

```
settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: ch], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: rate], AVSampleRateKey,
                                      [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
            nil];
```

NumberOfChannels and SampleRate received from base video.